# Use twitter API to extract tweets Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API to extract tweet updates from a user on twitter.

Here is how I am proceeding:

I am using this script to request the user JSON file and use it in the callback function.

```html
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/DoucoureEt.json?callback=updateTweets"></script>
```

Here is my updateTweets function:

```js
function updateTweets(tweets) { 
  var tweetSelection = document.getElementById("tweets");

  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    tweet = tweets[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = tweet.text;
    option.value = tweet.text.replace("\"", "'");
    console.log("The option is: " + option);

    tweetSelection.options.add(option);
  }

  tweetsSelection.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: it is not working

Comment: I am not getting anything back from twitter, I am supposed to get tweets back from twitter through this script tag that I included: <script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/DoucoureEt.json?callback=updateTweets"></script>

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong api in my script tags.

Comment: You cannot use a .json file in <script> tags. Browsers will refuse to execute it.

Comment: @Douk, right. Didn't see the end of the URL. Like @Private_GER said, you can't use it in a script tag. You can pass it as a URL param for `fetch`.

Comment: Can I use it as an URL in my call back function? I am not familiar with fetch().

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Tweets of an user, you have to use the following Twitter API endpoint:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

In your case, the full URL you'd have to hit is `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=DoucoureEt`. Be aware that this endpoint requires you to supply valid authentication data, otherwise you will not be able to use it, as it is a protected API endpoint.

Consider using fetch() to retrieve the Tweets asynchronously, decode the JSON data and then feeding it into your updateTweets() function.

Comment: I need an API that uses a call back function, do you know any? I am not familiar with fetch()

Comment: As said, use fetch(). It's the best option available for this. [This is a good tutorial for it.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data)